# How can I vectorize the loop in this sapply call?

Tags: r

I have found that the most expensive part of my R code is the following `sapply` call:

```r
L <- 2000
score <- sample(1:3, L, replace = TRUE)
d <- c(0, -1, 0.5)
sapply(1:L, function(i) sum(d[1:score[i]]))
```

That call takes the sum of the vector `d` from index 1 to index `score[i]`, looping over each element in the variable `score`. The challenge is that this code is evaluated as part of an optimization routine and run many, many times.

I am trying to perform the same computation in a vectorized way, but struggling a bit. I suppose that I could create a matrix like this:

```r
d.mat <- matrix(rep(d, L), nrow = L, byrow = TRUE)
```

then somehow compute `rowSums(d.mat)` but from column 1 to column `score[i]` in row `i`.  Is anyone aware of a way to do that without looping? I imagine that that would be much faster than `sapply`, if possible at all, given the relative speed of `rowSums` in the following benchmark:

```r
library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(sapply(1:L, function(i) sum(d[1:score[i]])), 
               rowSums(d.mat),
               times = 100)
```

Or perhaps someone sees a better third option.

Answer (score 9):

Index the `cumsum`:

```
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  sapply = sapply(1:L, function(i) sum(d[1:score[i]])),
  index = cumsum(d)[score],
  check = "equal"
)
#> Unit: microseconds
#>    expr    min      lq     mean  median     uq    max neval
#>  sapply 2494.8 2698.00 3232.279 2805.35 3516.2 6868.4   100
#>   index    4.3    5.05    8.682    6.90    8.9   60.2   100
```